# Android app for joining several photographs into a larger flat image

Tags: android, photography, image-editor, stitching

I want to take some large photographs of objects on the floor by taking several images and stitching them together.

I've tried out some panorama apps, but while they automatically stitch the images nicely, they "bend" them to the usual panorama projection.

Are there apps which can automatically stitch into a large flat picture? What's the name of this type of software?

Comment: If it's different photos/motives you want to join, that's called a "collage" or "photo grid". And you can [find some fitting apps in my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit#group_220). As I have not tried any such app myself, I unfortunately cannot recommend one – but the list should get you started.

Comment: No. It's not a collage. It's a number of images of different parts of the same thing, stitched into a single large image. Like what a panorama does, but without being distorted to a view from inside.

Comment: Panorama doesn't have to distort. In fact I have never seen it do so. There are many excellent free Panorama programs for desktop and, in this case. it might be better to use one. When stitch together pictures of “objects on the floor”, it might be better to use a large screen, to verify that the edges are stitched well.

Comment: you can't keep straight lines being straight in panoramas because there's no way to map very wide scenes (like 180° or more) to a flat image without curving those lines. In order for the images to be combined directly and still being straight you have to move the camera side to side, which is not easy to do

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot Join](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aufait.mindster.screeeenshot&hl=en)

> Join Screenshot app helps you to merge multiple screenshots into a
>   long picture - Share a long text conversations or a website with
>   friends. Don't clutter your friends with tons of screenshots, but send
>   just one image!

You can select desired images from your gallery to join into a large image

[image]

Comment: Good for screenshots, but what about photos, as the OP will use, where edges might not align, the pictures could be rotated a few degrees, etc?

Comment: You can use all images(I.e ss,photos etc)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Research has an image composite editor: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/product/computational-photography-applications/image-composite-editor/

There is also AutoStitch which is a technology licensed in some commercial products. See http://matthewalunbrown.com/autostitch/autostitch.html

Maybe one of these helps you, or point you in the right direction.