# Android app to stitch multiple photos together?

Tags: android, photography, image-editor, stitching

I've found it to be extremely convenient to both snap and crop photo with my phone before uploading it somewhere without the need to copy it over to my computer for editing. The default photo editor on my Android device does this just fine. But it has no feature for stitching a collection of photos together.

Is there a free or other (paid/no ads) photo editor for Android that will allow me to quickly stitch multiple photos together either horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35632/android-app-for-joining-several-photographs-into-a-larger-flat-image

Comment: I have used [Bimostitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.rethinkvision.Bimostitch) in the past (back when I still had Google-stuff on my phones), which worked quite well. It also has an advanced pro version (paid) which gives additional features – I didn't try that one, though.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I don't need photos stitched together as the app you linked advertises. I just want to combine pictures for places like Reddit where I may be able to only post a single picture but want to include more than one angle.